# Evaluate multivariable function with changing dimension of input

Tags: matlab, math

Given a function f:R^m -> R^n, where m,n change all the time. What would be the best way to implement this into a Matlab function that evaluates the output at an arbitrary point x∈R^m.

The fact that the function is vector valued, i.e. its target space is multidimensional, is easy to take care of using an array of anonymous functions. Then we can use a simple loop:

```
function testFunc(f,x)
resultArray = zeros(numel(f),1);
for kk = 1: length(f)
    resultArray(kk) = f{kk}(x);
end
resultArray
end
```

In the m=1, n=3 case with the following function

```
f = {@(x) (x*x); @(y) (exp(y)); @(z) (cos(z))}
```

yields the expected output

```
testFunc(f,2)

resultArray =

4.000000000000000
7.389056098930650
-0.416146836547142
```

If m were to be fixed, then this could be easily extended to the multi-variable case. But I do not know the value of m in advance.

How to tackle this problem? Thanks in advance.

---

Example. Say that I successfully implemented my function testFunc. Then the command prompt should be like this:

```
 >> f = @(x,y) (x*y);
 >> g = @(x,y,z) (exp(x*y*z));
 >> h = {@(x,y) (log(x*y)); @(x,y) (sin(x*y))}
 >> p = [1;2];
 >> q = [1;2;3];
 >> testFunc(f,p)
 ans = 
       2
 >>testFunc(g,q)
 ans =

       4.034287934927351e+02
 >> testFunc(h,p)
 ans =
       0.693147180559945 
       0.909297426825682
```

Comment: What if replace resultArray(kk)  by resultArray{kk} in order to make a cell array. Then x can be a vector

Comment: @freude I don't see how an array would help. Take for example the 'functions' f = @(x,y) (x*y) and g= @(x,y,z)  (exp(x*y*z)) and the points p=(1,2) and q=(1,2,3). Then testFunc(f,p) should output 2 and testFunc(g,q) should output exp(6). But I can't change testFunc inbetween.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what the output should be like for `m` (the size of the input vector) being anything other than 1. Can you give an example for `m = 2`?

Comment: @MartinJ.H. I presume you mean m=2? In that case, look at my comment above.

Comment: @MartinJ.H. I also edited my post with a example output in the end.

Comment: ok, does it work if just after the function definition title we put "x=num2cell(x);"

Comment: Hi Nigel, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your own starting point, this is the solution you are looking for. At least, if I understood your problem correctly. It gives the desired output for your test cases. The principle used is that of [comma separated lists.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)

```
function testFunc(f,x)

    x=num2cell(x);

    resultArray = zeros(numel(f),1);

    if ~iscell(f)
        f={f};
    end

    for kk = 1: length(f)
       resultArray(kk) = f{kk}(x{:});
    end

    resultArray

end
```